# How can i deploy my project on django-cms to an ubuntu vps?

Tags: deployment, vps, django-cms

I searched and tried many times. But always get stuck in deploying my project to ubuntu VPS. 
Can anyone please write the steps and commands that i have to do to deploy my django-cms project on a new Ubuntu VPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx and uWSGI are good choices for Django deployment.

Take a look at this documentation and follow the steps:
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)

This documentation is more like a tutorial and also it will fully guide you through the steps of setting up a Django web server with uWSGI and nginx.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying a basic Django CMS application is the same as deploying a Django project. Take a look at the official Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/ or follow step-by-step tutorials on deploying Django projects.